# zipfile extract zip to a folder

Tags: python, python-zipfile

**Below is what file structure looks like**

```
music_folder
    album1.zip (below are contents inside of zip)
        song1.mp3
        song2.mp3
        song3.mp3
    album2.zip (below are contents inside of zip)
        song12.mp3
        song14.mp3
        song16.mp3
```

I want to extract both zipped albums into a directory called `cache` and I want the same structure. **This is what I want it to look like:**

```
cache
    album1 (this is a normal unzipped folder)
        song1.mp3
        song2.mp3
        song3.mp3
    album2 (this is a normal unzipped folder)
        song12.mp3
        song14.mp3
        song16.mp3
```

But for some reason, for `album1` the files are extracted directly in `cache` directory instead of `cache/album1`.

**This is what it looks like and I don't want this**:

```
cache
    song1.mp3
    song2.mp3
    song3.mp3
    album2 (this is a normal unzipped folder)
        song12.mp3
        song14.mp3
        song16.mp3
```

**Below is my code:**

```
for zipped_album in os.listdir('music_folder'):
    zip_ref = ZipFile('music_folder/' + zipped_album, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('cache')
    zip_ref.close()
```

Any ideas why the files are not extracted in a folder inside `chache` for `album1`? It works for `album2`

Comment: The zip file doesn't have that structure, and your code doesn't create it. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip files can contain (relative) pathnames, not just filenames.

So, the contents of `album2.zip` are most likely actually:

- album2/song1.mp3
- album2/song2.mp3
- album2/song3.mp3

… but `album1.zip` is just:

- song1.mp3
- song2.mp3
- song3.mp3

To test this, you can do `unzip -l album1.zip` and `unzip -l album2.zip` from your shell.

---

This is actually a problem that people have been having as long as they've been sharing zipfiles. You usually want to include that `album2` in the paths, but sometimes it's missing. You don't want to forcibly add it and end up with `album2/album2/song1.mp3`, but you don't want to not add it and end up with just `song1.mp3` in the top directory.

The solution that most GUI tools use nowadays (I think it dates back to the ancient Stuffit Expander) is this:

- [Iterate all of the zip entries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) and see if the pathnames all start with the same directory.
- If so, unzip them as-is.
- If not, create a directory with the same name as the zipfile (minus the `.zip`), then unzip them into that directory.

---

The one tricky bit is that zipfile paths can be Windows or POSIX format, and they can be absolute paths or UNC paths or even paths starting with `..`, and the logic for transforming those to usable paths is, while not exactly *difficult*, more than just a one-liner. So, you have to decide how far you want to go with making your code fully general.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and solution